# Menu toggle contents slides multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On the mobile-version of my page, I have this infinite scroll mechanism for the contents feed. And to cope up with this, I need to make a nav menu to appear and positioned to fixed when the user scrolled to a certain offset.

I was able to do that except I encounter a problem that occurs with the toggle menu button and the slide transition for the menu contents. It seems that the menu slides multiple times (back and forth). I have attached a jsFiddle link to simulate my problem.

HTML:

```
<div id="menubar">
    <div id="menu">
    </div>    
</div>
 <div id="contents">
     <a>item 1</a>
     <a>item 2</a>
 </div>
```

jQuery script:

```
 $(window).scroll(function (event) {
     if($(window).scrollTop()  > 100){                
         show_menu();
     }
     else{
         hideAll();
     }  
 });

function show_menu(){
    $("#menubar").show();
    $("#menu").click(function(){
        $("#contents").slideToggle();
    });
}
function hideAll(){
    $("#menubar").hide();
    $("#contents").hide();
}
```

[Problem simulation in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/81q3k188/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens in your code is that you are adding a click event for the #menu every time you call the show_menu() function which is triggered every time you scroll above that offset. So the slideToggle is triggered as many times as the click events that were added.

To prevent this, you can either:

1. Add the click event outside the show_menu() function. (Better put it inside $(document).ready or window.load())

or

2. Use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** or jQuery [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) & [.unbind(](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)) function. Like this:

   ```
   $("#menu").bind("click",function(){
           $("#contents").slideToggle();
   });
   ```

   and use unbind before calling show_menu() to remove all the binded click event handler for the menu button:

   ```
   $("#menu").unbind("click");
   ```

   **[EDIT: Updated fiddle using bind and unbind](http://jsfiddle.net/81q3k188/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

change your :

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
     if($(window).scrollTop()  > 100){                
         show_menu();
     }
     else{
         hideAll();
     }  
 });
```

to

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    if($(window).scrollTop()  > 100){   
        $("#menu").unbind("click");             
        show_menu();
    }
    else{
        hideAll();
    }  
});
```

and

```
$("#menu").click(function(){
       $("#contents").slideToggle();
   });
```

to

```
$("#menu").bind('click',function(){
       $("#contents").slideToggle();
   });
```

or

```
$("#menu").on('click',function(){
       $("#contents").slideToggle();
   });
```